# RxSwift Using Variables Correctly

Tags: swift, mvvm, architecture, rx-swift

I am trying to convert a project to use RxSwift and MVVM. I have a service that syncs a list of data from Parse on every app launch and I basically want to make sure I am taking the correct approach.

What I have done is made a Variable subject and then allow my models to listen to this.
ParseService:

```
let rx_parseMushrooms = Variable<[ParseMushroom]>([])
```

MushroomLibraryModel:

```
_ = parseService.rx_parseMushrooms
    .asObservable()
    .map { (parseMushrooms:[ParseMushroom]) -> [Mushroom] in
        let mushrooms = parseMushrooms.map { (parseMushroom:ParseMushroom) -> Mushroom in
            let mushroom = Mapper<Mushroom>().map(parseMushroom.dictionaryWithValuesForKeys(parseMushroom.allKeys()))
            return mushroom!
        }

        return mushrooms
    }
    .subscribeNext({ (mushrooms:[Mushroom]) -> Void in
        self.mushrooms = mushrooms
        print(mushrooms)
    })
```

I do the same for expressing the sync state.

ParseService:

```
struct SyncState {
    enum State {
        case Unsynced, ConnectingToServer, SyncingInfo, FetchingImageList, SyncingImages, SyncComplete, SyncCompleteWithError
    }

    var infoToSync = 0
    var imagesToSync = 0
    var imagesSynced = 0

    var state = State.Unsynced
}

let rx_syncState = Variable(SyncState())
```

I then update the variable a la

```
self.rx_syncState.value = self.syncState
```

SyncViewModel:

```
_ = parseService.rx_syncState
     .asObservable()
     .subscribeNext { [weak self] (syncState:ParseService.SyncState) -> Void in
          switch syncState.state {
              //show stuff based on state struct
          }
      }
```

Anyways, I would greatly appreciate if someone can tell me if this is a good way of going about it or if I am misusing RxSwift (and guide me on how I should be doing this).

Cheers!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hmm... Here is an article about using Variable (note that Variable is a wrapper around BehaviorSubject.)

http://davesexton.com/blog/post/To-Use-Subject-Or-Not-To-Use-Subject.aspx

In your case, you already have a cold observable (the network call,) so you don't need a Subject/Variable. All you need to do is publish the observable you already have and use replay(1) to cache the value. I would expect a class named something like `ParseServer` that contains a computed property named something like `mushrooms`.

To help get the mushrooms out of parse, you could use this (this will create the cold observable you need):

```
extension PFQuery {

    var rx_findObjects: Observable<[PFObject]> {
        return Observable.create { observer in
            self.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ results, error in
                if let results = results {
                    observer.on(.Next(results))
                    observer.on(.Completed)
                }
                else {
                    observer.on(.Error(error ?? RxError.Unknown))
                }
            })
            return AnonymousDisposable({ self.cancel() })
        }
    }

}
```

And then you would have something like:

```
class ParseServer {
    var mushrooms: Observable<[Mushroom]> {
        return PFQuery(className: "Mushroom").rx_findObjects
        .map { $0.map { Mushroom(pfObject: $0) } }
        .publish()
        .replay(1)
    }
}
```

I think the above is correct. I didn't run it through a compiler though, much less test it. It might need editing.

The idea though is that the first time you call `myParseServer.mushrooms` the system will call Parse to get the mushrooms out and cache them. From then on, it will just return the previous cashed mushrooms.

Comment: Awesome and thanks for the reply :) What about for the sync state part? Basically I have a service class that does a bunch of stuff until the library is synced. This "syncLibrary()" method gets called on app launch but I want several classes to be able to listen to the state of sync in case new mushrooms become available. I also have the initial screen in which I show the progress of sync. Would you also make syncLibrary a var? This is the app btw in case it explains better what I do goo.gl/xJaV0d it's already out I'm just trying to master RxSwift it keeps blowing my mind..

Comment: Cool looking app. Like the article I referenced says, you rarely need subjects (including variable.) I think they are mainly in the library for those times when you have something that for example takes a delegate instead of a call back and you want to convert that into an rx stream.

Comment: In the case of syncing, your DB code should already be wrapped so that it returns observables. Kind of like what I did above for PFObject. Subjects are for generating hot observables from nothing. Your DB should not be generating hot observables.

Comment: Yeah. I guess I'm still wrapping my head around hot vs cold observables. This makes sense. Thanks again

Comment: Easy way to think about it. When you subscribe to a hot observable, all it does is add the observer to its list of observers. When you subscribe to a cold observable, it adds the observer to the list *and* starts some sort of process. So for example UIButton.rx_tap is hot, PFQuery.rx_findObjects in my code above is cold (a new server call is made for every subscription.)